# I would like to loop through my table called actors_videos which contains the id's from the actors and videos tables

Tags: php

I would like to loop through my table called **actors_videos** which contains the id's from the actors and videos tables.

The reason why I want to loop through is because I want to display the **actors_name** and use it as an anchor text. The **actors_id** should be included in the url as shown in the echo statement below.

The current code is only displaying one of the actors for the specified video-id which is wrong. I want it to loop through and display all the actors related to the video-id.

I would greatly appreciate any help from the community. I have been struggling to find the solution to this problem.

Regards,

This is the code that I have: [loop through the actors_videos table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXb5z.png)

```
//get stars
$result4 = $conn->query("SELECT actors_videos_id 
       FROM actors_videos 
       WHERE videos_actors_id={$_GET['video-id']}") 
    or die($mysqli->error);
$stars = $result4->fetch_assoc();
$stars = is_array($stars)? array_values($stars): array();
//loop through stars
for ($i = 0; $i < count($stars);$i++) {
    $star = $conn->query("SELECT * 
                           FROM actors 
                           WHERE actors_id = '{$stars[$i]}'")
               ->fetch_assoc();
    $s = count($stars) > 1 ? 's' : '';
    echo $i == 0 ? "<p><strong>Actor$s: </strong>" : '';
    echo "<a href='actors.php?actors-id=".$star['actors_id'].
         "&clean-url=".$star['actors_clean_url'].
         "' title='".$star['actors_name'].
         "' style='display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #cecece; line-height: 15px; padding: 3px 8px 4px; border-radius: 3px; margin: 2px; box-shadow: 0 0px; text-decoration: none;'>".
         $star['actors_name']."</a>"; 
}
```

Comment: Your code is really difficult to read, can you indent it? In any case, you're sending a separate query for each record in `$stars`, that's really inefficient and could make it more difficult to understand what you are doing. Try to get all the data in one query.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure how to indent on here. The reason why its two queries is because the first one selects the actors_videos_id FROM actors_videos table and the second one selects the actors ids from the actors table.

Comment: A JOIN between the two tables seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well fetch_assoc fetches only one table row. So the first call to fetch_assoc will fetch one actor id. You need to use [fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). It will fetch ids of all actors.